# How to implement extremely high floating point precision in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, precision

It is well known that Scheme can produce extremely large whole numbers without any further effort.

But how do I implement extremely high floating point precision, please? Thank you.

(by "extremely high", I mean a prescribed precision, like 1000, or 10000 digits after dot)

Comment: See if the scheme you're using has a binding  to GMP etc. available as a library.

Comment: I'm still newbie, have not known how to import a lib yet. I will check it out. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you solution works, Wll. But for other operator other than /?

Comment: The `/` is used internally, for the rounding. I've posted an answer which also talks about `*` etc.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick-n-dirty solution you can use ratios of integers, and round the interim results from time to time to the needed precision, so the computations do not become exceedingly slow.

Symbolically,

```
round_prec( Ratio(a,b), prec)  =  Ratio( round(a*10^prec / b), 10^prec)
```

where `Ratio(a,b)` is a symbolic data, e.g. tagged list `(list 'RATIO numerator denominator)`.

In Scheme,

```
(define (round-prec num denom prec)
   (list 'RATIO
         (round (/ (* num (expt 10 prec)) denom))
         (expt 10 prec)))
```

This works because `/` works with the integers properly, and we are being careful to multiply by `10^prec` first, *before* the division and, then, rounding.

Used as e.g.

```
> (round-prec 10 3 1)
'(RATIO 33 10)
> (round-prec 10 3 10)
'(RATIO 33333333333 10000000000)
```

This can easily be printed after converting it to the regular floating point with `(exact->inexact (/ num denom))`, e.g.

```
> (exact->inexact (/ 33333333333 10000000000))
3.3333333333
```

You can define the usual numeric operations easily as e.g.

```
mult( Ratio(a,b), Ratio(c,d)) = Ratio( (a*c), (b*d) )

sum( Ratio(a,b), Ratio(c,d)) = Ratio( (a*d + c*b), (b*d) )
```

etc. Other functions can be calculated using their Taylor series expansion.

A question arises though about the potential loss of numerical precision, as more and more roundings are performed. So you most likely need to work with more digits than your desired final precision. To find out how many are really needed for a given code is the whole separate science. I think there are some libraries that produce both the number and its error interval, as a result.

Comment: Thanks, Will. But for trigonometrics, log, and so on?

Comment: Taylor series maybe? Of course there's the external library...

Comment: Btw, your code needs one more step: output as decimal format.

Comment: I've added the floating conversion, after which you get the usual decimal representation. :)